# android search these strings if found then give message

Tags: android

i have a new project open on the project i have 1 textview and one button

i want to search for any of those strings below and if found then show a message

found 
not found

```
6A
6B
6C
6D
7A
7B
7C
7D
8A
8B
8C
8D
9A
9B
9C
9D
0A
0B
0C
0D
```

so people wil enter 2 code from above and if textview matches with the code then give found.

example

```
 Button clickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        clickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText tvId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
                TextView tvIdd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (tvId.equals("6A")){
                    tvIdd.setText("6a is nor");
                } else   if (tvId.equals("6B")){
                    tvIdd.setText("6b is nor");
                } else   if (tvId.equals("6C")){
                    tvIdd.setText("6c is nor");
                } else   if (tvId.equals("6D")){
                    tvIdd.setText("6d is nor");
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the list and check the first char, if the first number is a hit, check the second char. If thats a hit, success

Instead of hardcoding in "6B", just take the string from file and compare that

`for(...;...;...)`

will be useful here

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to see if the string matches a set of strings is to define a Set and then use the contains API:

```
private static final Set<String> mValues;
static {
    mValues = new HashSet<>();
    mValues.add("6A");
    mValues.add("6B");
    // add others
}

Button clickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
clickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText tvId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        TextView tvIdd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        String value = tvId.getText().toString();
        if (mValues.contains(value)) {
            // your edit text contains one of the strings, do your stuff here
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**STEP 1**

It’s easy to create and use a static array of strings in Android. You can do this in Java code, but for Android it's more easy by doing this in XML.

This is how you define a static string array in an Android XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="myStrings">
        <item>6A</item>
        <item>6B</item>
        <item>6C</item>
        <item>6D</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Then you can fetch this in java code as

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] myArray = res.getStringArray(R.array.myStrings);
if (Arrays.asList(myArray).contains(yourInputFromTextView)) {
    // true
}
```

**STEP 2**

This is the simplest way if your string always follows a pattern

```
public boolean isInputCorrect(String s){
    String pattern= "^[67890][ABCD]$";
        if(s.matches(pattern)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the strings 6A, 6B... into a hash table, and compare it with the text you get from the EditText widget, this can avoid tens of if-else branch.

example:

```
String inputText = tvId.getText().toString();
if (hashTable.containsKey(inputText)) {
    tvIdd.setText(intputText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    final String[] test={"6A","6B","6C"};
    final EditText tvId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final TextView tvIdd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    Button clickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    clickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for(int i=0;i<test.length;i++){
                if(test[i].equals(tvId.getText().toString())){
                    tvIdd.setText(test[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```